# Formatting a list of floats

Tags: python, list, format

I've got to format with a `%.02f` style my floats.

I've tried:

```
e =[0.2941, 0.1176, 0.0588, 0.2352, 0.1176, 0.1764]
print([float(".02f" % x)  for x in e])
```

but it fails, so I tried:

```
print( list(map( '%.02f'.format  , e )) )
```

It fails too, I found this one on the net:

```
print( list(map( '%.02f'.__mod__ , e )) )
```

It gives me a list of strings, so that I succeded to format with two commands:

```
ee = map( '%.02f'.__mod__ , e )
ee = map( float , ee )
```

OK it finally works but I shall miss something easier, no? Is it possible to use list comprhensions syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `%` in your original code, which is why it doesnt work. Use `float("%.02f" % x)` instead of `float(".02f" % x)`:

```
>>> e =[0.2941, 0.1176, 0.0588, 0.2352, 0.1176, 0.1764]
>>> print([float("%.02f" % x)  for x in e])
#                 ^the % is missing
[0.29, 0.12, 0.06, 0.24, 0.12, 0.18]
```

Alternatively, use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> print([ round(x,2)  for x in e])
[0.29, 0.12, 0.06, 0.24, 0.12, 0.18]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use round(x,2) for rounding to desired level

```
e =[0.2941, 0.1176, 0.0588, 0.2352, 0.1176, 0.1764]
print([float("{0}".format(round(x,2)))  for x in e])
```

hope this helps